# Ada compilation confusion

Tags: ada, gnat

I am trying to get my head around OOP in Ada. In order to do so, I need to understand how to name, compile and link package files with gnatmake.

This website (http://www.infres.enst.fr/~pautet/Ada95/chap22.htm) has good examples, but I don't understand how to compile the various bits of the program.

I am looking at e_c22_p2.ada and e_c22_p3.ada. From these I created a file called Conveyance1.ads and added the content of e_c22_p2 into this, and a file called Vehicle1.adb and added the content of e_c22_p3.ada in there. I used gnatmake Vehicle1.adb, but there are compilation errors.

e_c22_p2.ada contains:

```
                                            -- Chapter 22 - Program 2
package Conveyance1 is 

   -- This is a very simple transportation type.
   type TRANSPORT is
      record
         Wheels : INTEGER;
         Weight : FLOAT;
      end record;

   procedure Set_Values(Vehicle_In : in out TRANSPORT; 
                        Wheels_In  : INTEGER;
                        Weight_In  : FLOAT);
   function Get_Wheels(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return INTEGER;
   function Get_Weight(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return FLOAT;


   -- This CAR type extends the functionality of the TRANSPORT type.
   type CAR is new TRANSPORT;

   function Tire_Loading(Vehicle_In : CAR) return FLOAT;

end Conveyance1;




package body Conveyance1 is

-- Subprograms for the TRANSPORT record type.
procedure Set_Values(Vehicle_In : in out TRANSPORT; 
                     Wheels_In  : INTEGER; 
                     Weight_In  : FLOAT) is
begin
   Vehicle_In.Wheels := Wheels_In;
   Vehicle_In.Weight := Weight_In;
end Set_Values;

function Get_Wheels(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return INTEGER is
begin
   return Vehicle_In.Wheels;
end Get_Wheels;

function Get_Weight(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return FLOAT is
begin
   return Vehicle_In.Weight;
end Get_Weight;


-- Subprogram for the CAR record type.
function Tire_Loading(Vehicle_In : CAR) return FLOAT is
begin
   return Vehicle_In.Weight / FLOAT(Vehicle_In.Wheels);
end Tire_Loading;

end Conveyance1;




-- Results of execution
--
-- (This package cannot be executed alone.)
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14901832). TL;DR - use `gnatchop` on the source files (`e_c22_p2.ada` etc) to create the source files that GNAT expects.

Comment: Does it make sense for a means of transportation to have -42 wheels?

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen yes it does - when you are transporting ICBM (or other big stuff) that is likely about the amount of wheels such vehicle will have.

Comment: @darkestkhan - I think you missed the sign. ;-)

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen Oh boy, you are right - I did miss it xD (-42 wheels? car with 42 wheels missing?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file `e_c22_p2.ada` contains two program units, the spec and the body of package `Conveyance1`.

Many Ada compilers would be quite happy with this, and it is possible with some difficulty to persuade GNAT to accept it as-is, but GNAT’s default is to expect one program unit per file, with the file name equal to the unit name in lower case (dots replaced by hyphens), and `.ads` for the spec, `.adb` for the body.

GNAT comes with a tool `gnatchop` (see [here](http://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/the_gnat_compilation_model.html#renaming-files-with-gnatchop)) which takes input files like your `e_c22_p2.ada` and splits them up into the source files that GNAT expects (`conveyance1.ads` and `conveyance1.adb`).

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this issue up. I am having a really difficult time trying to wrap my head around some of the concepts in Ada. There does not seem to be a lot of easy to use reference materials on line, and the books I got hold of aren't much of a help either.

Comment: Have you looked [here](http://www.adaic.org/learn/materials/#ada_2012_books)? People speak highly of [Ada Distilled](http://www.adaic.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/Ada-Distilled-24-January-2011-Ada-2005-Version.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Simon, this .ada file has two sections : specs and body.
So create two files as below:

1. Conveyance1.ads - it contains the declarations of functions, procedures, variables
2. Conveyance1.adb - it contains the bodies of the functions, procedures

   The first file

```
-- Conveyance1.ads
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    package Conveyance1 is 

   -- This is a very simple transportation type.
   type TRANSPORT is
      record
         Wheels : INTEGER;
         Weight : FLOAT;
      end record;

   procedure Set_Values(Vehicle_In : in out TRANSPORT; 
                        Wheels_In  : INTEGER;
                        Weight_In  : FLOAT);
   function Get_Wheels(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return INTEGER;
   function Get_Weight(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return FLOAT;


   -- This CAR type extends the functionality of the TRANSPORT type.
   type CAR is new TRANSPORT;

   function Tire_Loading(Vehicle_In : CAR) return FLOAT;

end Conveyance1;
```

And second file,

```
-- Conveyance1.adb
------------------------------------------------------------------
package body Conveyance1 is

-- Subprograms for the TRANSPORT record type.
procedure Set_Values(Vehicle_In : in out TRANSPORT; 
                     Wheels_In  : INTEGER; 
                     Weight_In  : FLOAT) is
begin
   Vehicle_In.Wheels := Wheels_In;
   Vehicle_In.Weight := Weight_In;
end Set_Values;

function Get_Wheels(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return INTEGER is
begin
   return Vehicle_In.Wheels;
end Get_Wheels;

function Get_Weight(Vehicle_In : TRANSPORT) return FLOAT is
begin
   return Vehicle_In.Weight;
end Get_Weight;


-- Subprogram for the CAR record type.
function Tire_Loading(Vehicle_In : CAR) return FLOAT is
begin
   return Vehicle_In.Weight / FLOAT(Vehicle_In.Wheels);
end Tire_Loading;

end Conveyance1;
```

These 2 are ada package files.
In order to use these you need to create another .adb (say demo.adb) file as below.
Then 'with' and 'use' these files in demo.adb

```
-- demo.adb
------------------------------------------------------------------
with Conveyance1; use Conveyance1;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;


procedure demo is
    my_scooter : TRANSPORT;
begin

    Set_Values(my_scooter, 3, 250.00);    -- it has a sidecar as well !!!!

end demo;
```

and then finally compile your code with

```
gnatmake demo.adb
```

it will compile your included packages as well.